# Problems with header fields in django rest framework HMAC module?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, hmac

So I've been trying to utilize the djangorestframework-hmac module (https://github.com/aaronlelevier/django-rest-framework-hmac) to secure a REST API with HMAC.  But I'm running into what would seem to be a fundamental problem with it: as with most HMAC schemes, the client needs to put the message signature in a header field named 'Signature', but the problem is that header field names get translated by Django ('Signature' becomes 'HTTP_SIGNATURE').
But I can see in the code for django-restframework-hmac that the server is looking for a header field called 'Signature'. Now the module comes with an example, which works, but in the example, the client is running Django, which I believe may somehow be skirting around the header-field translation problem.  But what if the client is *not* using django?  How could the client possibly get his header fields seen by the server?  Is there something I'm missing here about the way django uses header field names?

Just to be explicit, here is the kind of request I'm making to test the client side:

```
headers = {'Key': api_key, 'Signature': sig, 'Timestamp': t}
DJANGO_URL = '127.0.0.1:8000/testrest/'
r = requests.get(DJANGO_URL, headers=headers)
```

But on the django server side, if I print out the request.META dictionary, the key corresponding to each of my header fields is altered ('Signature'->'HTTP_SIGNATURE', etc).  Yet the django HMAC code is looking for a field named 'Signature' in the request.META.  This behavior is even there in the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META).

I'm just wondering if this is a bug in the django hmac library, or if I'm not sending my request properly or something.

Comment: Please provide example code, because I'm unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Kamil, I added some more detail and code snippet

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in djangorestframework-hmac
Someone created identical issue on github

https://github.com/aaronlelevier/django-rest-framework-hmac/issues/4

And I noticed that tests in this lib use mocked requests so header is never rewritten by django and the bug was unnoticed

https://github.com/aaronlelevier/django-rest-framework-hmac/blob/master/tests/test_authentication.py

Comment: well, that was me; I first tried on github, but didn't get a response, so I tried here next.  Luckily, the code is not very long, so I can probably fix it pretty easily.